# Get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when I get the NSFileModificationDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I try to get the last modification date of a file:

```
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError *err;
NSDate *lastModif = [[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:filename error:&err] objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];//filename is ok ;-)
if(err == nil) {
    [lastModif retain];
    //I can put a NSLog of lastModif here, it works !!
    NSTimeInterval lastModifDiff = [lastModif timeIntervalSinceNow];//crash here
}
```

I don't understand why the NSDate seems to be released, why the retain does not retain it.

Thank you if you have any idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to retain `lastModif`.  I think you might be trying to treat `lastModifDiff` as an object of some sort when you do an NSLog with it or whatever you do with it afterwards.  `NSTimeInterval` is a typedef to a double so you need to treat it as a double or `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lastModifDiff]` if you want to use it like an object.

Comment: I don't do anything with lastModifDiff for the moment, it crashes at allocation, because lastModif seems to be nil according to the debugger.

Comment: I'm running your code now.  I take out the unnecessary release and add an NSLog() after setting lastModifDiff.  Both values are set for me.  Are you sure your filename is correct?

Comment: Yes, I can load it with NSKeyedUnarchiver, and [fm fileExistsAtPath:filename] is YES.

Comment: Run the code with the debugger and when it crashes type "where" into the console, maybe that will help us figure out what is going on.  I copied and pasted your code into a new Xcode project, putting in a file path for something on disk, and I'm not crashing.  Also try a clean build perhaps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't really understand why, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, but this post seemed germane:

[NSDate : timeIntervalSinceNow crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994275/nsdate-timeintervalsincenow-crash)

I'm writing a simple set of functions- startClock/endClock -using NSDate to determine FPS in my game loop. Except that timeIntervalSinceNow crashes, claiming that my earlier set NSDate object doesn't exist.

I know for a fact that the NSDate object has a retain count of 1 when I call startClock, but my theory is that NSDate instances are internally rigged to auto-release when they get bored and aren't feeling useful.

Using retain/release to assume ownership of these flighty and ephemeral NSDate objects worked for me.