# NSDate : timeIntervalSinceNow crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I want to display, on screen, the elapsed time since some event.  I have a member variable

```
NSDate *_startTime;
```

I allocate it (and initiate a timer) like so:

```
_startTime = [NSDate date];
_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(clock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

My clock function gets called fine but when I attempt to find the elapsed time I get a crash with no real way of determining what happens; I simple get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  Below is how I attempt to get the elapsed time since `_startDate` which throws the exception:

```
NSTimeInterval secondsElapsed = [_startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

It crashes on this line - I have looked around and this seems to be the correct syntaax, what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using ARC, you need to have ownership of the `NSDate` object that you're storing in `_startTime`. `+[NSDate date]` returns an object you don't own, and it is likely to have been deallocated and therefore to be invalid by the time you get around to sending it `timeIntervalSinceNow`.

You can create an owned `NSDate` like so:

```
// By default, NSDates are initialized with the current date
_startTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

or by explicitly taking ownership of the return value of `+date`:

```
_startTime = [[NSDate date] retain];
```

They are equivalent in effect.

Even better (assuming you have a property defined for `_startTime` (which you should)) would be using the setter:

```
[self setStartTime:[NSDate date]];
```

With the property defined as `retain`ing, this will handle the memory correctly.

Comment: Thanks - P.s. how do I output the interval as a time i.e. 01:30

Comment: P.p.s why should I define a property for internal member variables?

Comment: An `NSTimeInterval` represents seconds; there are 60 seconds in a minute. Use the division and modulus operators, or the `ldiv()` function. There are a number of questions on SO for that.

Comment: Why define a property? It makes the memory management much easier. It's possible to do without it. It's also possible to declare the property in an "internal" class extension.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to `retain` your `_startTime`, otherwise it gets autoreleased. (Of course, once you retain it, you are responsible for releasing it later.)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't retain `_startTime`, so it may have been deallocated by the time your timer fires.

Answer (score 0):

[NSDate date] will return an autoreleased object. It will be deallocated once out of scope. If you want to use it in your 'clock' function you will need to retain it.